# How to deserialize the request body AsSingleObject while also passing parameters from the route?

Tags: routes, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a pretty standard route like this, `{controller}/{action}/{id}`, where id is optional.

Consider these three PUT actions:

```
public void DoSimpleStuff(int id) {/*DoingStuff*/ }
public void DoMoreStuff(StronglyTypedObject sto) {/*DoingStuff*/ }
public void DoExtraStuff(int id, StronglyTypedObject sto) {/*DoingExtraStuff*/ }
```

DoSimpleStuff works out of the box.

To make DoMoreStuff work I needed to [disable the model binder](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Disabling-model-binding-in-9f965fcd). So I implemented a custom `IRequestContentReadPolicy` returning `RequestContentReadKind.AsSingleObject`.

However, that doesn't fix DoExtraStuff.

So my question is, what can I do to fix DoExtraStuff? Shouldn't the route understand that only the last parameter comes from the content, and hence pass that type to my serializer?

PS: I realize they'll change how this work, but I need a solution for this now. Creative answers appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In asp.net mvc 4 beta this was hard to do. In fact I had to work around it as I didn't find a way (if there was one) to achieve this.

However, in asp.net mvc 4 rc you simply apply the `[FromBody]` and `[FromUrl]` attributes to your action parameters, and you're good to go. Nice! :)